# error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, mingw

The error I am getting is " error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 "

The command I'm using is: python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32

I'm on Windows XP and I installed minGW. I am trying to use kinterbasdb for python.

Answer (score 0):

That means it did not use mingw32 as a compiler. In the terminal type

```
which mingw32
```

If that does not return anything the system does not know that this compiler is installed. That could be the problem. Then you'd have to add the compiler to the path variable and try again.